# emacs editing Rnw keep region highlighted when highlighting R chunk

Tags: emacs, r, sweave

When editing an Rnw file in Emacs, I often want to make the region cover a chunk of text that contains an R chunk. For a simple example:

```
ewr
<<>>=
@ 
wer
```

I use transient-mark-mode such that the region is highlighted. But, if I put the point on the first line and hit C-SPC, then use C-n to move the point down, the highlighting disappears when I try to advance the point past the <<. The region I want is still selected, but highlighting seems to fail when crossing the <<. How can I fix this?

Thanks and best regards

Answer (score 4):

I find that your problem shows up when I do what you describe, but it goes away if you scroll down using <kbd>C</kbd>-<kbd>down</kbd> or <kbd>C</kbd>-<kbd>M</kbd>-<kbd>n</kbd> instead. I think you can even use <kbd>C</kbd>-<kbd>down</kbd> to get past the R chunk and then <kbd>C</kbd>-<kbd>n</kbd> to step past lines afterward.

Comment: I have to have a blank line above <<>> and below @ AND have no blank lines between <<>> and @ AND use the `C`-`down` after doing a `C`-`SPC` with the cursor above the blank line above <<>>.  I'm still waiting/searching for a fix.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and the solution suggested by fojtasek did not work for me because I had an additional configuration problem.  I hope that this might be useful for you and other users.  Make sure that if you are using ESS and Auctex that you have fully loaded Auctex.  To be more specific, it turned out that when I had previously installed auctex 11.86, I did not correctly load the package.  Because I am a novice emacs user, I only managed to load the first of the following two lines:

```
(load "auctex.el" nil t t)
(load "preview-latex.el" nil t t)
```

If you have not added the second line, you will only have an Auctex menu but NOT a preview-latex menu.

Comment: Adding those 2 lines unfortunately did not affect the noted behavior for EMACS version 24.4 (http://vgoulet.act.ulaval.ca/en/emacs/windows/).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Fojtasek for the C advice. I find C- with the arrow key will keep a contiguous highlight.  C-down brings up a page that says "this confusing feature has been disabled by default".

In my opinion, this behavior that OP complained about is a flaw in Auctex, and the fact that Fojtasek has a way to avoid it is helpful, but still it is just a workaround. I don't want Auctex to to this and I don't really want to have to use my left hand for holding down C while scrolling. PITA.

If Auctex needs some special selection tool, they should have to use unusual keystrokes for that. Why impose it on the rest of us who just want to highlight big sections and move them around, whether or not they have <<>> in them.